# Js big switch statement, best way to do it

Tags: javascript

Which of the two approaches is better in performance and memory usage?

Approach 1

```
const lookup = {
  case1: () => { /* action for case 1 */ },
  case2: () => { /* action for case 2 */ },
  // ... other cases
};

switch (expression) {
  case 'case1':
    lookup.case1();
    break;
  case 'case2':
    lookup.case2();
    break;
  // ... other cases
}
```

Approach 2

```
function lookup(caseName) {
  switch (caseName) {
    case 'case1':
      return () => { /* action for case 1 */ };
    case 'case2':
      return () => { /* action for case 2 */ };
    // ... other cases
  }
}

lookup(expression);
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: `let case = 'case1'; lookup[case]();` ...? If you can't be sure that `lookup[case]` will actually exist for the given `case` value, then check it's existence first.

Comment: I cannot tell about performance, it depends on a lot of factors that cannot be listed here, but the polymorphism that you present calls for an OOP approach, especially if this is only one of the many `switch`es already present (or what will emerge) in the code. A properly implemented OOP makes all the `switch` statements vanish, except for one that decides what class to instantiate.

Comment: Depends on the contents of each *case* function. Do the functions contain similar logic?

Comment: Approach 1 is the same as 2, except you add an other call to a const. Why make it more complicated than it is?

Comment: As stated, there doesn't seem to be a definitive answer, except for maybe abandoning the switch completely and simply calling the lookup directly (you can kind of use an object like a switch). Only important thing to note: "return" will stop executing the whole function, while "break" will just stop executing the switch-block, so with approach 2, make sure there is no more code in the function below the switch to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an object instead.

```js
lookup_table = {
'case1': () => { console.log("case 1"); },
'case2': () => { console.log("case 2"); }
}

expression = 'case1';
lookup_table[expression]()
```